# Where are "Disks" in the new Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Where will I find my disks in the new Azure portal?
I've deleted a virtual computer, but I can't delete the blob because "it's currently in lease." Microsoft addressed this issue [in an article they published 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/02/05/iaas-unable-to-delete-vhd-there-is-currently-a-lease-on-the-blob.aspx) but haven't updated it since the new portal replaced the previous one earlier this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources are of type "OS Disks (Classic)" Here's how I found them in the UI.  (after using the search bar at the top of the portal and it didn't return anything for "disks").

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I needed. :) Merry Christmas!

Comment: Zanathel, where did you try looking? Would love to know how we can make this more obvious. (I'm on the Azure portal team.)

Answer (score 2):

you'll find them is OS Disks (Classic).

```
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseServiceBlade/assetTypeId/Microsoft_Azure_Classic_Compute_Disks
```